# Html css div is not showing on left

Tags: html, css

I am facing this issue,  div is not showing on left side it's showing in the middle.

As you can see in the image white div is showing in middle I need to show it in left.

[image]

Html

```
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="first-layer">
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.slide{
  background-color: #f4525e;
}

.first-layer{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 93%;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5%;
}
```

Also i am strung to do border radius like this but its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `margin-left: 0;` for `.first-layer`

```css
.slide {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f4525e;
}

.first-layer {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 93%;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="first-layer">
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```